# Laravel 5 detach / remove polymorphic relation

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism, relation, detach

I've got a `transactions table` in which I can storea polymorphic relation, either `payment` or `plan`. What I cannot seem to get is, when I update an existing transaction, and I remove the `payment_id` or `plan_id` in the form, how to clear that relation from the database.

When inserting (or updating), this works fine:

```
$payment->transactions()->save($transaction);
```

I've tried a lot of things, and the `detach` method doesn't work, since it's not a many to many relation.

My models:

Transaction:

```
public function paymentable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Payment (and Plan):

```
public function transactions()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Transaction::class, 'paymentable');
}
```

Any ideas?

Basically my question is this, how can I clear the `paymentable_id` and `paymentable_type` when I perform an update on an existing transaction, when no `payment` or `plan` was submitted? So basically, when the `payment` or `plan` was removed from the form. I prefer not to use some RAW query.

Comment: Does `$payment->transactions()->delete();` not work for you?

Comment: That actually deletes the whole record from the database, or I am doing something wrong. Will test it again.

Comment: According to Laravel documentation ([https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships)) you can use dissociate method to unlink all relationships you don't need

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either, tried that. Just says it's an unknown method. And I just cannot find anything about `detaching` or `disociating` a polymorphic relation anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User @zgabievi's comment is correct. `dissociate()` has been around since 5.0. Here's the commit that added it to the `MorphTo` relationship: https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/3d6727e1764c37e1219b0a1fc7e003ef61615434#diff-4c052acf0022213a4cc23f53ba42720e

I have used this method to dissociate polymorph files records from their parent model. Because it is in `MorphTo`, the `dissociate()` method is called on the child.

Example:

```
$attachment = new Attachment; // contains 'attachable' morphTo relationship

$note = new Note; // contains morphyMany relationship to Attachment

// save the Attachment through the attachments relationship, sets morph fields and persists to the database
$note->attachments()->save($attachment);

// populate the morph fields without saving
$attachment->attachable()->associate($note);

// clear the morph fields without saving
$attachment->attachable()->dissociate();
```